# bash-4.3 How to interpret a string expression in bash as boolean

Tags: bash, shell, boolean

I have a Array like this

```
T[1]="x>1";
T[2]="y<2";
 .
 .
```

and some assignments like that

```
x=2;
y=10;
.
.
```

Finally, I need a logic based on the following terms

```
logic_value1=${T[1]} # but this is just a string and not Boolean 
logic_value2=${T[2]} #  ....." " "....
.
.
```

Can anybody Help? (I write in a procedure and therefore **eval** can not be used, and query Like that:

```
 select * 
 from table1 
 where  condition1 AND logic_value1
```

)

but for integer value of logic_value1 this Condition and query didn't work

Comment: What does "I write in a procedure" mean?

Comment: This strongly depends on what is in the `. . .`. `I write in a procedure and therefore eval can not be used` Why? How is "writing a procedure" related to restriction of not using eval?

Comment: Informix SQL procedure, and variables are defined out of procedure, but operations inside

Comment: `declare -i logic_value1` (before the assignment), will cause any string assigned to it to be interpreted as an arithmetic expression. Example `a='4>1'; declare -i b=$a; echo $b` => `1`. But that is an obtuse and obscure feature, and you better don't write "logic" in bash.

Comment: Voting to close as extremely unclear. If you want these expressions to be interpreted by SQL, they have to be strings in Bash (which doesn't have any other atomic data type than strings anyway).

Comment: `bool=(FALSE TRUE); logic_value1=${bool[T[1]]}; logic_value2=${bool[T[2]]}`

Comment: @user431397  :Based on your idea    bool=("1<>1" "1=1"); logic_value[1]=${bool[T[1]]}; logic_value[2]=${bool[T[2]]}   It works perfectly, but if variables with the $ prefix -external-are in the condition statement-T[1,2]-, it will no longer work, and this problem has not yet been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case using arithmetic expansion would suffice.

```
T[1]="x>1";
T[2]="y<2";
x=2;
y=10;
logic_value[1]=$((${T[1]}))
logic_value[2]=$((${T[2]}))
declare -p logic_value
# outputs: declare -a logic_value=([1]="1" [2]="0")
```

Comment: There is still a problem and this TERM is not "AND" or "OR" with other TERMs because it is an INTEGER

Comment: You don't need the `${...}`; `logic_value[1]=$((T[1]))`

Comment: @alwaystudent `There is still a problem` What problem? `this TERM` What is "this TERM"?  What is a "TERM"? I do not understand the rest at all. I do not know what is a "AND" and what is an "OR" and what other "TERMs" there are and in what context what is an "INTEGER". I also do not understand why these terms are written in upper case. Please kindly explain it.

Comment: @KamilCuk :   As mentioned in the title, the string should be converted to Boolean, not Integer, and double parentheses are a way to calculate numerically.

Comment: `to Boolean, not Integer, and double` shell has __only__ strings. there are no variables types. All variables store strings. There is no "boolean" "integer". A variable content (a string) may be interpreted as a number inside specific contexts, like arithmetic expansion. But these all are strings. So, well, please specify what a "Boolean" is and what is a "Integer" and how they differ. If you want to store the string `true` inside variable content, then do that `if ((${T[1]})); then logic_value1=true; fi`

Comment: @KamilCuk :   I corrected the question, can you answer again

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. You have to explain the context you are working with, the environment you are working with. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), about [folllow up questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions), [why is help me not a real question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and I recommend [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: And [what is an XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Remember - creating a good [MCVE] will help getting good answers.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Anyway, your solution was very close